# Many-to-many w/ extra columns + Spring Form Binding

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have searched high and low, but cannot find an answer:  I'm trying to save a ManyToMany entity (contains audit columns) via a form using spring MVC.  I apologize for the long post, but want to include as much information as possible.  I have 3 entities, User, UserRole, Role, and I want to update the UserRole relationship via a form:

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User extends AuditableEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new LinkedHashSet<UserRole>();

}
```

**UserRole:**  Note the **AuditableEntity**!

```
@Entity
@Table
@IdClass(RoleId.class)
public class UserRole extends AuditableEntity {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private User user;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private Role role;
}
```

**Role:**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Role extends AuditableEntity {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

Pretty straightforward, right?  All 3 tables extend an AuditableEntity, which has a listener set up to auto-populate date created/updated and created by /updated by.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot for the life of me UPDATE the UserRole objects.  I have set up a list of checkboxes via spring forms:

```
        <form:checkboxes path="user.roles" 
                        items="${roles}" 
                        itemLabel="name"
                        label="Roles"
                        itemValue="id" />
```

I've tried creating a converter to convert the Role IDs into `UserRole` objects:

```
public class UserRoleConverter implements Converter<String, UserRole> {

    private RoleManager roleManager;

    public UserRoleConverter(RoleManager roleManager) {
        this.roleManager = roleManager;

    }

    @Override
    public UserRole convert(String source) {
        Role role = roleManager.findOne(Integer.valueOf(source));

        UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
        userRole.setRole(role);

        return userRole;
    }
}
```

and this works fine when the user does not have any roles.  However, when updating a user's roles, I get a NULL SQL error because it's overlaying the proxied UserRole (from the database) with the UserRole created by the converter.  Hibernate sees this as an updated object, not a new object, so it skips the audit listener for setting the date created timestamp.  Additionally, I'm not sure how to go about *removing* roles via this method.

Is there a way to simply map User -> Role via @ManyToMany with the audit columns being populated via a listener?  Any thoughts are appreciated!

Thanks.